# OpenGL ES set array of vectors

Tags: java, opengl-es, glsl

I would like to set `uniform vec2 positions[10];` in my fragment shader code to java array. How can I do that? I guess I need to do something with `GLES20.glUniform2fv` but I don't really know how to use it.

Comment: Google found something: [How to use `glUniform2fv`method in android.opengl.GLES20](https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/android.opengl.GLES20/glUniform2fv), [How to use `glUniform2fv`method in org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20C](https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/android.opengl.GLES20/glUniform2fv)

Comment: `glUniform2fv` is the correct function. You just have to copy the code from the examples. Where do you struggle? If I answered your current question then I would just copy the code from the examples. I have no idea what else could be missing. Make an effort to ask a good question a little more. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Ok, sorry. This actually works, the problem wasn't actually with glUniform2fv, it was with other function that I have written the wrong way. It works now but I still dont really know why. Can you explain why value 'count' should be set to array.lenght/2?

Comment: The elements of the array are floats. A Uniform of type `vec2` has 2 components (floats). Therefore the number of uniforms is NumberOFloats / 2.

Comment: Ok it makes sense, thank you for help!